# Holomorphic dynamical systems defined on a contractible bounded open subset of $\Bbb{C}^n$

Tags: reference-request, ds.dynamical-systems, complex-dynamics, several-complex-variables

Let $U$ be a contractible bounded open subset of $\Bbb{C}$. There is a standard classification of possible dynamical behaviors of holomorphic maps $f:U\rightarrow U$:

1. **Attracting Case**: There is an attracting fixed point in $U$ to which all orbits converge.
2. **Escape**: For any compact subset $K$ of $U$, the intersection $f^{\circ n}(K)\cap K$ is empty for $n$ large enough.
3. **Finite Order**: Some iterate of $f$ is identity.
4. **Irrational Rotation**: There is an $\alpha\in\Bbb{R}-\Bbb{Q}$ such that $f$ is conjugate to $\Bbb{D}\rightarrow\Bbb{D}:z\mapsto{\rm{e}}^{2\pi{\rm{i}}\alpha}z$.

A proof can be found for example in Milnor's book on complex dynamics.

**My question**: What is known or can be said when $U$ is a contractible bounded open subset of $\Bbb{C}^n$? Are there examples of holomorphic maps $f:U\rightarrow U$ that exhibit a different dynamical behaviors; that is, $f$ is of infinite order, is not conjugate to a linear map, does not have any attracting periodic point, and admits orbits with accumulation points inside $U$.

Comment: E. Vesentini, Su un theorema di Wolff et Denjoy,  Rend. Sem. Mat. Fis. Milano 53 (1983), 17–25 (1986).